TypeScript Utility Type NestedKeyOf with Dotted Notation Fails in Strict Mode
I'm using a custom TypeScript utility type NestedKeyOf to extract nested keys as dotted notation strings, such as "parent.child". The type works as expected with "strict": false in tsconfig.json, but enabling "strict": true causes issues, particularly with optional properties.
Here's my NestedKeyOf type definition:
    type NestedKeyOf<T> = T extends object
       ? {
            [K in keyof T & string]: T[K] extends object
              ? K | `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<T[K]>}`
              : K;
         }[keyof T & string]
       : never;

This type works as expected during Angular's compilation when "strict": false is set in angularCompilerOptions in tsConfig.json
Example Code:
Here's an example with the following types:
export interface Node {
  name: string;
  version?: string;
  ip_address?: IPAddress;
}

export interface IPAddress {
  ipv4?: string;
  ipv6?: string;
};

I expect the following code to compile:
const nkn: NestedKeyOf<Node> = 'ip_address.ipv6';

Link to StackBlitz
I've created a Example to reproduce the issue.

• Angular isn't really relevant here; please [edit] this to use a [mre] without it. You could copy the text from this playground link which shows the same issue. • The check T[K] extends object is bad because if T[K] is a union of an object and a non-object, your code treats it as a pure non-object. With strict on, the non-object undefined is present in your optional properties, and . You probably want to distribute over unions, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Thanks @jcalz. I have updated the question. Please post your answer, I will approve it. Thanks for the quick help.

The problem you're having is that the T[K] extends object check is false when the property T[K] is a union of an object type like IPAddress with a non-object type like undefined.  With the --strictNullChecks compiler option enabled (which happens automatically with the --strict suite of compiler features), optional properties automatically get undefined added to their types. So IPAddress | undefined does not extend object and thus your NestedKeyOf does not drill down into that type.
You apparently want to say that if you have a union like IPAddress | undefined you should drill down into it as if it were just IPAddress (despite the fact that someNode.ip_address.ipv6 might turn out to throw a runtime error if the ip_address property is missing). One possible approach here is to just say if a property is of type X | Y you should allow keys of X and you should also allow keys of Y.  So if you had {prop: Node | IPAddress} then you'd allow "prop.name" and "prop.ipv4", for instance.  There are other possible approaches, of course, which work for your example but differ in how edge cases are treated. I'll consider that out of scope for the question as asked.
So if you want X | Y to treat X and Y separately and put the result in a union, then you want to distribute the check over unions in T[K]. And the easiest way to do that is to make it a distributive conditional type, by giving it its own generic utility type (since distributive conditional types only happen when the type you're checking is a bare generic type parameter like type Foo<T> = T extends ⋯ and not something more complicated like type Foo<T> = T[K] extends ⋯):
type NestedKeyOf<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T & string]:
  NestedKeyOfProp<T[K], K>;
}[keyof T & string] : never;

type NestedKeyOfProp<TK, K extends string> =
  TK extends object ? K | `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<TK>}` : K;

I've basically broken that check out into NestedKeyOfProp<T[K], K> which is now distributive over unions in T[K]. So NestedKeyOfProp<IPAddress | undefined, K> is equivalent to NestedKeyOfProp<IPAddress, K> | NestedKeyOfProp<undefined, K>, which is K | `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<T[K]>}` | K or just K | `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<TK>}`, as desired.
Let's test it:
type NKN = NestedKeyOf<Node>;
//   ^? type NKN = "name" | "version" | 
//        "ip_address" | "ip_address.ipv4" | "ip_address.ipv6"

const nkn: NestedKeyOf<Node> = 'ip_address.ipv6'; // okay

Looks good.
Playground link to code

You need to markup the object as having all keys required.
For example if ip_address is optional it's value is IPAddress | undefined which isn't a subset of object:
type T = Node['ip_address'] extends object ? true : false // false

So you need to make all object keys required in order to drill down into the child objects:
Playground
type NestedKeyOf<T extends object, R extends Required<T> = Required<T>> =  keyof {
    [K in keyof R & string as R[K] extends object ? K | `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<R[K]>}` : K]: any
}

Another way is to handle the optional prop manually:
Playground
type NestedKeyOf<T extends object> =  keyof {
    [K in keyof T & string as T[K] extends undefined | object ? K | `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<Exclude<T[K], undefined>>}` : K]: any
}


Could you please help me understand how Required has helped solve the problem? And what is the issue with not using it?

@SaiSatwikKuppili added the explanation to the answer
